# Is there a difference between 0 and -0 in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In Javascript when you multiply

`1 * 0 = 0`

whereas

`-1 * 0 = -0`

Well, I can understand its technically 0, is there something different between 0 and -0 under the hood?

Comment: Yes, its how floating point numbers are represented, and is the reason `float === float` is often best avoided.

Comment: mathematically they are equal, but in binary they are represented differently. specifically the first bit is a 1 instead of 0 for -0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting! It seems their values are equal--neither is larger than the other, but they are distinct objects with several side effects (including division by `0` or `-0` as per Roisin's answer).

Other interesting quirks observed:

```
const a = 0;
const b = -0;

a == b; // true
a === b; // true

a < b; // false
b < a; // false

Object.is(a, b); // false
Object.is(a, -b); // true

b.toString(); // "0" <-- loses the negative sign

a + b; // 0
b - a; // -0
a * b; // -0
```

Comment: This is true, depending on the equality comparison you use. For example. Object.is(+0, -0) === false

Comment: The == and === in JS treat signed and unsigned 0 the same. This is standard in many (most?) languages that follow the IEEE-754 model, often requiring a different method to detect.

Comment: Having it like this is also uniform with x <= 0, x >= 0, x <= -0, and x >= -0. (Arguments about proper methods to compare aside.)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a difference. JavaScript has *signed zeros*, so the two are represented differently internally.

There are some practical differences too:

```js
console.log(1 / +0 ===  Infinity) // true
console.log(1 / -0 === -Infinity) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

When you compare `0 === -0` you will get `true` but if you check with `Object.is(0, -0)` you will get `false`.

[Object.is()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is)